# El compilador de SQL server marca error en todas las columnas "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, select

El error sucedió en microsoft sql server management studio 18.9 en su version de desarrollador y antes no aparecía ningún error al consultar de la base de datos de Northwind, y ahora si me da el fallo de Invalid column name, incluso cunado ejecuto todo sale bien y me ejecuta la sentencia.
[image: Todas las columnas de la base de datos Northwind me dan el error "Invalid column name", pero al ejecutar consultas o cualquier sentencia si sirve e incluso me trae las tablas como se muestra en la imagen, solo que me marca en rojo los nombres de cada columna]

Comment: Saludos Victor, Bienvenido a SO. La captura de pantalla ayuda mucho, pero también hace falta que coloques la consulta completa.

Comment: Esque no es problema de la consulta, ya que todo lo que hago siempre marca el error en el nombre de la columna en todas las consultas y en todas las bases de datos , tanto que pienso que puede ser la configuración del sql server. Además lo estaba probando con northwind y unicamente le di click derecho y generar scrips y metí el de select, es un select hecho por el propio sql server

Answer (score 2):

Ese error no lo está dando el *compilador*. De hecho SQL no se considera un lenguaje *compilado*, por lo que en muchos motores no hay siquiera un *compilador*.

El error se muestra en la interfaz de usuario como una indicación de que podría haber un error en el nombre de columna y es parte de [intellisense](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/scripting/intellisense-sql-server-management-studio). Al escribir texto en el Editor del SQL Server Management Studio, tras bambalinas está corriendo un *parser* para *interpretar* el código que escribimos, con la intención de brindarnos ayuda, por ejemplo, con la sintaxis de la consulta.

También se mantiene un *cache* de la estructura de la base de datos que estamos usando en el momento, que es en el que el IDE se basa para mostrarnos las tablas disponibles al llegar a la cláusula from, por ejemplo.

Esta información no se está consultando todo el tiempo desde el motor de base de datos, por razones de rendimiento, no tanto del Management Studio, como del motor de la base de datos, ya que podrías estar conectado a un entorno de producción.

Hay ocasiones en los que este caché se puede quedar desactualizado, porque ejecutamos un script que crea nuevos objetos o miles de otros casos. Dado que la consulta se ejecuta sin problemas, es evidente que tu caché se quedó desactualizado en el momento que escribiste la consulta. No podría explicar la razón por la que esto pasa, pero si como resolverlo:

Puedes utilizar la combinación de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, o bien ir al menú:

- Edit

  - Intellisense

    - Refresh local cache

[image: Menú Edit/Intellisense/Refresh local cache]

Esto forzará a leer de nuevo el diccionario de datos y ya con eso el subrayado rojo de las columnas debiera desaparecer.

Debes tener en cuenta que esto funcionará para la base de datos que tienes en uso, si tu consulta involucra tablas de una base de datos secundaria, no digamos de un servidor remoto, estos diccionarios de datos no son consultados por intellisense.

Comment: Puede que el problema mio sea algo más complicado, ya borré el caché local, incluso desinstalé el sql server y lo volví a instalar y me sale el mismo fallo.

Comment: ¿Has revisado la configuración? En el artículo vinculado se encuentra un link a la misma.